# Modal is showing first element in array of angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-modal

This Html code helps in repeating out the company profile in a card-block.

```
 <div class="container-fluid" id="gallery" ng-controller="ComController" style="padding-top: 2em;">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">Campus Recruiters</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" ng-repeat="company in companies">
          <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">

            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" ng-src="{{company.com_logo}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-block">

              <h5 class="card-title">{{company.com_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{company.com_abt}}</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" ng-click="setSelectedItem(company)">About {{company.com_name}}</button>
             <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" ng-model="selectedItem == company"> //Button to actiavte modal
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{company.com_name}}</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>                  
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the ComController i am using.
Now I can't figure out why only 1st element is showing wheni click on button for modal.

```
app.controller('ComController', ['$scope', function($scope){


    $scope.setSelectedItem = function(item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    };


    $scope.companies = [

        {

            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/tcs_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Tata Consultancy Services',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },
        {
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/hcl_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Hindustan Computers Limited',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/hp_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Hewlett Packard',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/ion_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Ion Trading',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/niit_logo.png',
            com_name: 'NIIT Technologies',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/techm_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Tech Mahindra',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },
        {
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/tcs_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Tata Consultancy Services',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },
        {
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/hcl_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Hindustan Computers Limited',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/hp_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Hewlett Packard',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/ion_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Ion Trading',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/niit_logo.png',
            com_name: 'NIIT Technologies',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        },{
            com_logo: 'recruit_icons/techm_logo.png',
            com_name: 'Tech Mahindra',
            com_abt: 'I am this company',
        }];


}]);
```

Comment: I don't see any `ng-repeat` in your HTML

Comment: I think your ng-click should be changed to pass the company name or anything unique to pop up  the corresponding company rather passing the company object itself

Comment: @tanmay it is right in the tag of button.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<div ng-controller="ComController">
<div ng-repeat="item in companies">
 <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" ng-src="{{item.com_logo}}" alt="Card 
image cap">
    <div class="card-block" >
      <h5 class="card-title">{{item.com_name}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.com_abt}}</p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" ng-click="setSelectedItem(company)">About {{item.com_name}}</button>
     <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" ng-model="selectedItem == company"> //Button to actiavte modal
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{item.com_name}}</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>                  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is doing same what my code was doing. only opening modal with first element.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I found some small mistakes in your html.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" ng-model="selectedItem == company">
```

The statement itself is worng as ng-model on div give non-assign exception. And ng-model does not assept conditions it only holds your modal object.

You can try this. It might help you.

```
<div ng-controller="ComController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in companies">
    <div class="card-block" >
        <h5 class="card-title">{{item.com_name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.com_abt}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" ng-click="setSelectedItem(item)">About {{item.com_name}}</button>
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" ng-if="selectedItem.com_name == item.com_name"> //Button to actiavte modal
                <div class="modal-content" style="color: lightblue">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{item.com_name}}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your angular code remain the same.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried but only first element is opening through modal, and others just give a black overlay.

Comment: It worked for me. Your issue may be of CSS or something else. So can you provide your example on JSFiddle so that I can exactly see what the issue is. Thanks